# Fazer buscas usando repetições

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Criei o seguinte método para buscar pessoas aleatórias de um certo partido, o problema é que se eu quiser adicionar mais dez pessoas de um outro partido ele não adiciona, só substitui a busca sem partido para partido tal

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
    class << self
        def filtra_pessoas()
            Pessoa.where(partido: "sem partido").order('rand()').first(10)
            #Pessoa.where(partido: "partido tal").order('rand()').first(10)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Até rola fazer, mas você vai ter um problema com registros repetidos. Isso é um problema pra você?

Comment: Repetir os registros é um problema sim, mas da forma como esta no momento não repete. 
acredita que não vai repetir, pois o mesmo partido não seja buscado mais de uma vez

Comment: Do jeito que está não vai repetir porque você só está buscando os primeiros 10, digo que existe uma solução para acumular outros 10 elementos, mas este vai causar problemas com duplicação.

Comment: Entendo, me mostra como pode ser feito e ai eu tento algo diferente, de inicio quero entender porque a query substitui a primeira busca pela segunda ao invés de acumular. nao sei se deu pra você entender =D
Sou novo no Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então *Erasmo*, esse tipo de consulta não vai acumular, pois é o comportamento normal de qualquer *query*: Buscar novos registros. Ou seja você vai ter que fazer essa acumulação manualmente, vamos tentar uma das possíveis abordagens:

Novamente o ideal nesse caso é que você utilize `scopes`, seu código fica mais limpo, *dry* e na prática o uso é similar. Só exemplificando ficaria assim:

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :filtra_pessoas, -> { where(partido: "sem partido").order('rand()').first(10) }
end
```

Agora voltando à pergunta, para acumular precisamos de um outro método para fazer o trabalho sujo:

**TR;DR**

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :filtra_pessoas, -> { where(partido: "sem partido").order('rand()').first(10) }
  @pessoas_aleatorias = []

  def self.acumula
    @pessoas_aleatorias += filtra_pessoas
  end

end
```

Salientando novamente que você vai ter o problema de registros repetidos que vai dar uma certa dor de cabeça pra resolver. Você pode usar o `uniq` para resolver isso, mas você não vai conseguir ter a quantidade fechada *10, 20, 30...* sempre, ou seja a solução para isso vai depender muito de seu modelo de negócio.